# Use FIRRTL Annotations to connect multi-bit wires and pins

Tags: scala, chisel, register-transfer-level

I am  writing down some firrtl transforms and I am using annotations to connect pins and wires, like :

```scala
 val named = ComponentName(inputWire.name, ModuleName(mod.name, CircuitName(top)))
 val anno = Traversable(SinkAnnotation(named, pinName))
```

The *inputWire* is :

```scala
 val inputWire = DefWire(NoInfo,localNS.newTemp, con.expr.tpe)
```

And the *pinName* is a string :

```scala
val pinName = namespace.newName(faultPinPrefix)
```

where the type of *inputWire* is *UIntType(IntWidth(2))* or it could be more than 2 on some other cases.

After this transform, I run the *firrtl.passes.wiring.WiringTransform* to issue the connections
The problem I'm facing right now is that the verilog output is like below :

```
input       faultPin_0
//...
//Some code
//..
 assign _GEN_1 = {{1'd0}, faultPin_0};
```

This is not the behavior I expect. It is creating an input port of 1 bit only, and it is concatenating it, it create the 2 bit signal. Maybe the problem is that I am not specifying the type of the port, I am letting the compiler decide for it, and it is automatically creating a 1 bit port. 
Is there any way to make this connection using annotations, or I should focus on finding another approach which is more feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WiringTransform` will wire multi-bit components and *does* [include a test of this](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/blob/621c5689ff9b441465a9e6a1f4d92af739603293/src/test/scala/firrtlTests/WiringTests.scala#L678).

However, the type of the pin is a function of the *source* and not a function of the *sink*. Can you verify that your source is also a multi-bit signal?

For the test referenced above the following FIRRTL:

```
circuit Top :
  module Top :
    input clk: Clock
    inst x of X
    x.clk <= clk
    reg r: UInt<5>, clk
  module X :
    input clk: Clock
    wire s: UInt<5>
```

And the following annotations:

- `SourceAnnotation(ComponentName("r", ModuleName("Top", CircuitName("Top"))), "pin")`
- `SinkAnnotation(ComponentName("s", ModuleName("X", CircuitName("Top"))), "pin")`

Produces the following circuit when run through the `WiringTransform`:

```
circuit Top :
  module Top :
    input clk: Clock
    wire r_0 : UInt<5>
    inst x of X
    x.clk <= clk
    reg r: UInt<5>, clk
    x.pin <= r_0
    r_0 <= r
  module X :
    input clk: Clock
    input pin: UInt<5>
    wire s: UInt<5>
    s <= pin
```

This seems to be right. However, if I make the source a 1-bit signal (`reg r: UInt<1>, clk`), then the pin will also be 1-bit (`input pin : UInt<1>`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it is more clear to me . I fixed it, the problem was the source type was not what I was thinking it was.